# How to aggregate data where instances occur over different time intervals

Tags: time-series, feature-engineering

I am working on a problem in which I have several instances that have predictors that have activity over various different time periods (i.e. <3 months to well over 20 months.) Originally I attempted to use knowledge I have about this problem (it is an opportunity to sale conversion model) and learned that the average time for a deal to close is about 9 months, so I broke my predictors up into three month intervals. However, I took another look at the lengths of these deals and see that there are a variety of instances that have durations that are not even close to 9 months so this idea does not make sense.

The only idea I have gotten is just creating a duration column where I subtract the start and the stop date and then just do the summation for each predictor. However, I feel that the instances might get incorrectly labeled because some might have an overwhelmingly higher amount of activity than another due to the duration of the deal. Has anyone else encountered such a problem. Not sure if this is a common problem but a quick glance at google/reddit did not come up with anything (I could be asking the problem wrong.)

Comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. you can use aggregation functions. For example use Max, Min, Avg, count, std or some calculation like the slope of the line. In cases which you have a different period, you can divide your value to days of each period.

Comment: So you just aggregated and divided by number of days or number of months? This is an interesting idea, but my original idea was trying to capture differences in the time period and how they might affect the prediction. Do you believe that this idea might be defunct due to the differences in duration?

Comment: yes, it works for me
and I divide values of each period by length of that period